# How can I avoid using a temporary file in this bash script?

Tags: bash, pipe, temporary-files, zenity

As a beginner with shell scripting, I've written this bash script function to return the md5sum of a file, while providing the user with a GUI progress bar.

```
md5sum_of_file () {
    (pv -n $1 | md5sum | sed -e 's/\s.*//g' > /tmp/md5sum) 2>&1 | zenity --progress --auto-close
    echo $(</tmp/md5sum)
    rm /tmp/md5sum
}
```

`pv -n $1` feeds the file into `md5sum | sed -e 's/\s.*//g'` (sed strips the output of the sum's associated filename), while piping a percentage to `zenity --progress --auto-close`.

I know you can't simply assign the checksum to a variable in this instance, as "(pv -n $1 | $(md5sum | sed -e 's/\s.*//g'))" is within its own subshell. But is there a way to do this without creating a temporary file (in this case "/tmp/md5sum")?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not: `pv -n $1 | md5sum | sed -e 's/\s.*//g' | zenity --progress --auto-close`

Comment: Your pipeline is really strange... so you do have an executable file that has the name of the md5 sum of what you're feeding through `pv`??? and you want to execute it?

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf -- oops sorry -- fixed that. I think the command substitution was left over from me trying to assign the md5sum to a variable in the parent shell (before I learned about variable scope in subshells). Just started trying to learn Bash today :P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that `zenity` is using is the standard error from `pv`, so use a process substitution to do that without involving any stdout or stderr from the other commands. This lets the output of `sed` simply go to standard output without the need for
any temp files.

```
pv -n "$1" 2> >(zenity --progress --auto-close) | md5sum | sed -e 's/\s.*//g'
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess this will do (with Bash):

```
md5sum_of_file() {
    local md5sum
    read -r md5sum _ < <( { { pv -n "$1" | md5sum >&3; } 2>&1 | zenity --progress --auto-close; } 3>&1)
    echo "$md5sum"
}
```

We're doing a little bit of plumbing here:

- `pv`'s standard output (i.e., the content of the file) is normally passed to `md5sum`, and `md5sum`'s output is redirected to file descriptor 3;
- the standard error stream of `pv` is then redirected to standard output to be fed to `zenity`;
- after this, we redirect file descriptor 3 (remember, it's `md5sum`'s output) to standard output, to be read by `read`;
- `read` only reads the first field of that (so that we don't need `sed` to cut the filename);
- finally, we `echo` the result.

If your function only does that (that is, you only want to `echo` the md5 sum), you could also do it thus:

```
md5sum_of_file() {
    { { pv -n "$1" | md5sum >&3; } 2>&1 | zenity --progress --auto-close; } 3>&1 | { read -r md5sum _; echo "$md5sum"; }
}
```